# Clone operation for printing failed

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

when I want to call the print window in Firefox, it throws the exception: `DOMException: Window.print: Clone operation for printing failed`. at chrome and etc that's alright.

this is code where throw exception:

```
const printHtml = (html) => {
  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = html;
  iframe.contentWindow.print();
  document.body.removeChild(iframe);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Either don't remove the iframe (hide it) OR use timeout to give the browser time to execute the code before pulling the rug from under it.

```
const printHtml = (html) => {
  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = html;
  iframe.contentWindow.print();
  setTimeout(() => iframe.remove(),1000);
};
```

Alternatively use a print CSS to hide all on the page except a div where you copy the html to

Comment: it doesnt help, i solve this with Blob